# How to parse and convert a text in Dart

Tags: dart

I have a text coming from the API like this:

> The temperature in the room is [{50°}{F}]

How i can parse this text from the brackets (read the values inside the bracket and remove the brackets) and convert it to Celsius ?

So the result can look like this

> The temperature in the room is 10° C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does look like something that is best handled by a RegExp.

```dart
RegExp _tempRE = RegExp(r"\[\{(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)°\}\{([CF])\}\]");
String convertTemperaturesToCelsius(String input) {
  return input.replaceAllMapped(_tempRE, (m) {
    var temp = m[1];
    var scale = m[2];
    if (scale == "C") return "$temp° C";
    assert(scale == "F");
    var fahrenheit = double.parse(temp);
    var celsius = fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);
    var dot = temp.indexOf('.');
    var decimals = dot < 0 ? 0 : temp.length - dot - 1;
    var celsiusString = celsius.toStringAsFixed(decimals);
    return "$celsiusString° C";
  });
}

double fahrenheitToCelsius(num fahrenheit) => (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;

// Example:
main() {
  var s = "ab [{50°}{F}] cd[{50.25°}{C}]..[{-12°}{F}]";
  print(convertTemperaturesToCelsius(s));
}
```

I chose to allow decimals on the numbers, and output with the same number of decimals as the input, and recognized both `{C}` and `{F}` as original temperatures.
Your details might vary.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer this helped me.
I have a question. If i want to do the same thing but with other scales for example `kg` to `lb`. How should the RegExp pattern be ?
Should i only change the `[CF]` to `[kglb]` ?

Comment: @x98 No, doing that would match k, g, l, and b, you should instead use a group match, instead of doing `([CF])` you should use `(lg|kg)`. (remember to remove the ° from the match if you don't need it)

Answer (score 2):

If you always have the same format with [{number}{F}] you can use these lines to split up the string and convert it to celsius:

```
String temp= "The temperature in the room is [{50°}{F}]";
double fahreneit=double.parse(temp.split("[")[1].split("{")[1].split("°")[0]);
double celsius= (fahreneit-32)*5/9;
print ("The temperature in the room is $celsius° C");
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for the answer. Yes the format will be always [{number}{F}]. But what if there are multiple lines of text where i should convert/parse multiple formats in a long text.
Also i don't want to print the text i want to show the `temp` string with the converted values.

Comment: If you have multiple lines (like a file or any other format) you can loop the code above. Of course I used the print function as an example, but you can you "celsius" wherever you want.